# How to calculate gcd?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Note, In this question: $(a,b)$ means gcd $(a,b)$

Given $(a,b)=2$ Plus, $5a+7b=2$

I need to calculate: $(7a+14b, 14a+21b)$

I did the following:

$$(7a+14b, 14a+21b) = (7(a+2b), 7(2a+3b)) = 7(a+2b, 2a+3b) = (4-3a, 6-a)$$

but stuck here...

Comment: $7(a+2b, 2a+3b)=7(a+2b, a+b)=7(b,a+b)=7(b,a)=…$

Comment: @Macavity you didn't explain anything... which didn't help at all

Comment: All you need is $\gcd(x,y)=\gcd(x, y\pm x)$. Once you show that, the above chain of equations will make sense.

Comment: $(a+2b,2a+3b) = (a,b)$ by the linked dupe.

Comment: See also the many "Linked" posts in the dupe for other methods.

Comment: @Macavity and how to prove this?

Comment: @Roy Try first principles - use the definition of gcd, should be enough to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $a=2p$ and $b=2q$ where $p$ and $q$ are coprime integers. Hence we get $5p+7q=1$. It can be shown that $p=3$ and $q=-2$ is a solution to this diophantine equation, thus a parametric form of the general solution is
$$\begin{cases}p=3+7t\\q=-2-5t\end{cases}$$
And that $\gcd(a+2b, 2a+3b)=2\gcd(p+2q, 2p+3q)=2\gcd(1+3t, t)$.
Since $\gcd(3t, t) = t$, it can be shown that $\gcd(1+3t, t) = 1$.

Hence $\gcd(a+2b, 2a+3b)=2$, and $7\gcd(a+2b, 2a+3b)=14$.